# Setting a div to display:none; using javascript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, mobile

I have a really quick question that should be an easy answer.

I have a mobile navigation menu that uses jQuery to "drill down" menu levels. Each time a level is loaded, the jQuery determines the menu's height, and sets it accordingly.

I am using the following script on a button to toggle show and hide the main menu based on the current page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function ($) {
        $("a.BNnavTrigger").click(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $("div.drill-down-wrapper").slideToggle("9000");
        });
    })(jQuery);     
</script>
```

In order for the menu to start "closed" on certain pages, I know that I must give the css value of `display:none;` to the containing div. This is all working fine with one small problem.

When I initially hide the menu, the jQuery drilldown menu plugin detects that it is hidden, and sets the menu height to 0px. When I toggle the menu on a page that had the menu initially hidden, all the other content in the pane toggles correctly, but the menu itself is stuck at a 0 height.

In my brain, the obvious answer to this problem would be to hide the containing menu div ,via javascript, after the menu has been loaded and it's height set. Does this sound correct?

Could anyone provide me with a little script to do this? I am a complete and utter noob with js. Does anyone else have a different recommendation as to how to handle this issue?

Thanks for your time!
Alex

**UPDATE!**

**JS fiddle for the issue here:** http://jsfiddle.net/fyyG2/17/*

Comment: Can you attach html file as well?

Comment: This is all very nice, but shouldn't you show us how you're loading this menu and setting it's height, if we're supposed to be able to help you with that part ?

Comment: @Edward - I've added the html I am using for the menu

Comment: @adeneo - It was a jquery menu that I purchased. I did not write the code, so telling you exactly where in it the height sizing functions reside will be hard. I can post the entire js file if you like.

Comment: Unless it *really needs* to set the height to a particular value to work, a simple `height: auto !important;` in CSS might "fix" the issue ..

Comment: If you're having trouble with something you purchased, it might be easier to contact your vendor for assistance.

Comment: @user2246674 The script is setting the #drilldown div with an inline css value of "height:0px;", even with "height:auto !important;" set on this same div, the menu still not displaying. The toggle view script I posted above is effectively un-hiding the menu though. I can tell this through firebug. Its just simply set to a height of 0px.

Comment: Is my original idea a bad one? Can I not simply give the css value of "display:none;", via javascript, after the page has been loaded?

Comment: It would seem it is. Just tried this, and no luck. document.getElementById('hide-me').style.display = "none";

Comment: hmm you can try to use visibility:hidden instead, maybe this helps?

Comment: Just wondering,  why would one purchase a drilldown menu when there are so many tutorials and free ones? E.g. http://effinroot.eiremedia.netdna-cdn.com/repo/plugins/menu-nav/drill.down/index.html# Also, please make a jsFiddle if you want us to be better able to help you.

Comment: @r3bel unfortunately, visibility:hidden does not trigger the slide:toggle event properly. Its just makes it so it's not seen.

Comment: @Tyblitz the menu was purchased for two reasons. 1. It was 5 dollars and 2. It was the only one I found that dynamically resized it's height based on the number of menu items displayed. I've never made a js fiddle, but I'll give it a go.

Comment: @DavidThomas I contacted the developer, and they confirmed that the menu will not calculate it's height correctly if it is not initially visible. They gave me the following tips:

I've discussed it with my team here and currently we can think of 2 hacks:
use visibility:hidden - this way drilldown will be able to calculate it's height but it will still reserve some space in layout
use visibility:hidden + position:absolute with left/top + z:index: 0 so that it won't overlap any element

Comment: @Tyblitz Here is the jsFiddle! http://jsfiddle.net/fyyG2/17/

Answer (score 17, accepted):

On **document ready** do `$("#yourId").hide();`.

For example:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

     $("div.drill-down-wrapper").hide();
     var $drillDown = $("#drilldown");

        // (what ever your code is)
 });
```

Comment: Could you show me what you mean by this in my jsFiddle? Thanks.. I'm fairly noob at js/jquery

Comment: $(document).ready(function () {
                $("div.drill-down-wrapper").hide();
  var $drillDown = $("#drilldown");........(what ever your code is)
});

Comment: Perfect. Menu loads, then hides. Toggle the re-shows. Thank You.

Answer (score 17):

Try this way:

```
$("#yourId").css("display","none");
```

it should work it!

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for this tip kiko-lp. Unfortunately, even when I hide the menu via JS after page load, the menu still detects it's hidden, and gives itself a height value of 0. I'm not aware of any way to delay this script so that the menu height would be set first.

Comment: I have created a jsFiddle for this issue. Check it out! http://jsfiddle.net/fyyG2/17/

Answer (score 2):

Adding css value display:none to your css file works just fine.
http://jsfiddle.net/dxkX6/4/

but I can see that you have a typo in your html file:

```
$("a.BNnavTrigger").click(function (event) {
       ^

<a class="BNavTrigger">Toggle Menu</a>
        ^
```

is that possibly the reason why you are experiencing the problem?

Comment: The typo error was in the transfer of the html to this page, but your right, it does work just fine.

The issue is that the jquery used by the purchased plugin requires itself to be visible initially in order for it to correctly calculate it's height.

Comment: I have created a jsFiddle for this issue. Check it out! http://jsfiddle.net/fyyG2/17/

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that I fully understood your problem, but here's a thought:

Set the opacity of what you wish to hide to 0, instead of changing it's size / hiding it. This way it will keep its dimensions but won't be seen to the users:

```
$('#id').css('opacity',0);
```

And to re-show the element:

```
$('#id').css('opacity',1);
```

Comment: Thanks for the thought Israel. I'm trying to toggle the menu using slideToggle so that I can hide the menu on mobile browsers. Meaning I need the height dimensions to change with the toggle as well. I have created a jsFiddle to show what I'm talking about here: I have created a jsFiddle for this issue. Check it out! http://jsfiddle.net/fyyG2/17/

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$('#id').style = "display: none;"
```