# Using jQuery .hide() with CSS media queries for menu toggle based on screen resolution

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a website using css media queries to detect browser resolution and modify my site accordingly.

I have run into a slight problem with my main navigation menu. There are a number of pages on my site where I would like to have my main navigation hidden on load for mobile resolutions, but displayed on desktop resolutions.

This seems like a simple enough task to accomplish with css, but unfortunately for me, it is not. I am unable to use both `display:none;` and `visibility:hidden;` because when my menu detects on load that it is hidden, it sets it's height to 0, and will not change.

Here is a stack overflow page reference:
[Setting a div to display:none; using javascript or jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16743611/setting-a-div-to-displaynone-using-javascript-or-jquery)

Ultimately, I the only option I found that would hide my menu on load, while still allowing the menu to correctly calculate it's height was the following bit of jQuery.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".hide-menu").hide();
    var $drillDown = $("#drilldown");
});
```

Now, this solution is working for pages that I would like to have the menu initially hidden on load for all screen resolutions. However, I have a number of pages on which I would like to have the menu hidden initially hidden on load for mobile, but displayed on desktop.

I have attempted to recreate this scenario in a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WRHnL/15/

As you can see in the fiddle, the menu system has big issue with not being displayed on page load. Does anyone have any suggestions on how I might accomplish this task?

Comment: You can also make something invisible by giving it `position: absolute; left: -10000px;`

Comment: yea instead of hiding it, just position it off screen, you can give it visibility hidden if you want to, but it is not needed

Comment: This is a good idea guys, and most likely what I should have done in the first place. If you take a look at my jsfiddle, you will see the jquery I use for my trigger button to toggle the menu. That will have to change so that instead of slidetoggling, it simply moves the div back into position on the screen. Any ideas on what that code would look like? I have no idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by comparing the screen-size:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var width = $(window).width();
    if (width < 768) {
        $(".hide-menu").hide();
    }
    var $drillDown = $("#drilldown");
});
```

Comment: I like this suggestion Markus, as it takes advantage of the setup I am currently using. For some reason though, your snippit causes the menu height to not calculate, while the one in my description that hides irrelevant of screen size does not. Any ideas on why that is?

Comment: Is it possible that my jquery for toggling the menu back into view is just not complete?:
    (function ($) {
        $("a.navTrigger").click(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $("div.drill-down-wrapper").slideToggle("9000");
        });
    })(jQuery);

Comment: maybe it needs some kind of .show() in it? The code is in the fiddle.

Comment: you can put everything together in one ready-function. Then move the "hide" to the bottom (after "manageBreadcrumbs();"). The reason for this: I'm sure that the plugin is trying to calculate the height of the elements. And that will be only possible if they are visible. The height will be 0 if the element is hidden.

Comment: That did it. When I added the script after the menu load script, the height calculates normally no matter the circumstance. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use !important to force to origional state via media queries. 
This will over-ride the "display:none" from your js.

Example:

```
@media (max-width:980px){ 
nav  > .btn-group{display:none}
}
```

Your Js then toggles style="display:block" or style="display:none"
you maximize the window and the below resets your origional style.

```
@media (min-width: 992px) {
nav  > .btn-group{margin:0px auto; display:inline-block !important}
}
```